# Stripe: how to get user email (and/or other info) and after payment redirect to a confirmation page?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I would like to sell a software using Stripe as payment gateway.

After a succesfully payment i want to redirect to a php page that get user email, and generate a serial number given that email.

I don't know how to:

- Redirect to a succesfully page
- Get the user email previously inserted by user

I have this listener from standard documentation:

```
// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
```

Is the one I've to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect by

```
// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

You can retrieve the email entered in the `stripeEmail` field when you POST the result of Checkout to your server, like this

```
  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'source'  => $token
   ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => 5000,
    'currency' => 'usd'
  ));
```

Here is the PHP + Checkout page in the Stripe docs, which goes over this:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/php